# IOS static debug symbol meaning

Tags: ios, multithreading, debugging, core-data, debug-symbols

I am getting this error and i am not able to figure out, where the heck is it going on.

Here is the stack trace:

```
0 CoreFoundation 0x382952a3 __exceptionPreprocess + 163
1 libobjc.A.dylib 0x3358d97f objc_exception_throw + 31
2 CoreData 0x398fe0cf -[NSComparisonPredicate(_NSCoreDataSQLPredicateCategories) minimalFormInContext:] + 371
3 CoreData 0x399097af -[NSCompoundPredicateOperator(_NSCoreDataSQLPredicateCategories) minimalFormInContext:ofPredicates:] + 727
4 CoreData 0x398fd917 -[NSSQLGenerator initializeContextForFetchRequest:ignoreInheritance:nestingLevel:] + 539
5 CoreData 0x398fd3b3 -[NSSQLGenerator newSQLStatementForFetchRequest:ignoreInheritance:countOnly:nestingLevel:] + 39
6 CoreData 0x398fd2bd -[NSSQLAdapter _newSelectStatementWithFetchRequest:ignoreInheritance:] + 509
7 CoreData 0x398fced5 -[NSSQLCore newRowsForFetchPlan:] + 117
8 CoreData 0x398fc64f -[NSSQLCore objectsForFetchRequest:inContext:] + 683
9 CoreData 0x398fc119 -[NSSQLCore executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 469
10 CoreData 0x398fb531 -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 1645
11 CoreData 0x398f9e2b -[NSManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:error:] + 647
12 CoreData 0x3996293f -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NestedContextSupport) _parentObjectsForFetchRequest:inContext:error:] + 399
13 CoreData 0x399630c9 __82-[NSManagedObjectContext(_NestedContextSupport) executeRequest:withContext:error:]_block_invoke_0 + 565
14 libdispatch.dylib 0x36eb2621 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_slow_invoke + 81
15 libdispatch.dylib 0x36ea34b7 _dispatch_client_callout + 23
16 libdispatch.dylib 0x36ea4dcb _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$up + 227
17 CoreFoundation 0x38268f3b __CFRunLoopRun + 1291
18 CoreFoundation 0x381dbebd CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 357
19 CoreFoundation 0x381dbd49 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 105
20 GraphicsServices 0x36f532eb GSEventRunModal + 75
21 UIKit 0x3a3882f9 UIApplicationMain + 1121
22 Sticky Free 0x000ac67b _mh_execute_header + 13947
23 Sticky Free 0x000ab1e0 _mh_execute_header + 8672


And here is the main error.
Invalid predicate: nil RHS
```

I know its from NSPredicate while doing a fetch. But , i am not exactly sure, which line is causing it. I am using a multithreaded coredata environment.

This issue is very intermittent and comes once in 10 sessions or so. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: This is a very strange looking stack frame: `22 Sticky Free 0x000ac67b _mh_execute_header + 13947`.  How are you viewing the crash (or where are you getting it from)?

Comment: Set breakpoint on Exceptions, than you'll see which line cause the error

Comment: and how does the predicate look, maybe an attribute value makes it go bahooka...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the others have said: do set a symbolic breakpoint on `objc_exception_throw` and see which one of your `executeFetchRequest` will trigger the error. 
From the line with the `executeFetchRequest` scroll up to where you define the predicate.

`RHS` tends to stand for Right Hand Side. Assuming you are setting up the predicate with:

`[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K = %@", attribute, value];`

then `RHS` will be `value`. Ensure that `value` is not `nil`.

Comment: Spot on and +1 for the explanation of what does RHS mean!

Answer (score 0):

What i found was, i was saving main context immediately on exit. So, if i dont save the maincontext on exit, i dont get this weird looking crash.